# Can I safely replace usesCleartextTraffic in my Manifest?

Tags: android, android-manifest, libraries

I am trying to use hCaptcha library on my project. However, it seems that hCaptcha library comes with a **usesCleartextTraffic** tag defined on the Manifest which is already defined by another library. When I add hCaptcha and try to run the project I get the following error:

```
Attribute application@usesCleartextTraffic value=(true) from [com.theoremreach:theoremreach:3.5.1] AndroidManifest.xml:15:9-44
is also present at [com.github.hcaptcha:hcaptcha-android-sdk:3.3.6] AndroidManifest.xml:11:9-45 value=(false).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:usesCleartextTraffic"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:17:5-132:19 to override.
```

Great, there is a suggestion. Now by adding the following to my application tag on the Manifest, I can avoid any errors and run my application:

```
tools:replace="android:usesCleartextTraffic"
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

My question is, replacing this value with **true** will not influenciate the hCaptcha Manifest **false** value for **usesCleartextTraffic**?

What would be the correct way to solve this error, without affecting each library security?